# Anchoring from a link to label in a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list on top of my page that has a few different countries on it. I need to have an #anchor that will pop half way down the page to the country picked. However the countries down the page are pulled from a Database and are listed by HyperLinks in a repeater.

```
<td align="center">
  <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
     <li><a href="#USA">USA </a></li>
     <li><a href="#Canada">Canada </a></li>
     <li><a href="#Australia">Australia </a></li>
  </ul>
</td>
```

---

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
  <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:HyperLink ID="hlCountryName" runat="server" Style="color: #6D94B8; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 10px;"></asp:HyperLink>
```

And inside the DataList1_ItemDataBound method in the C# section I did:

```
hlCountryName.Attributes.Add("href", "#" + drCountry[Common.Data.Country.Constants.countryName].ToString());
```

Yet when I click on the link at the top of the page I am not taken anywhere. I am wondering what I could be missing in my code? Or if I have miss understood how to do this altogether? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You should try to set the _name_ attribute of your hlCountryName (and remove the **#** from the value being set)

Comment: I tried this, but it still just sits there doing nothing when I click on one of the countries. Any other suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just try to replace this line :

```
hlCountryName.Attributes.Add("href", "#" + drCountry[Common.Data.Country.Constants.countryName].ToString());
```

with :

```
hlCountryName.Attributes.Add("name",drCountry[Common.Data.Country.Constants.countryName].ToString());
```

Comment: That worked great. Thanks for showing me that! I really appreciate it